# Cache to Local Storage in WebView android

Tags: android, webview

I am showing a html page in to webview using URL and I want to store that html file from webview cache to local storage of device. Is it possible, Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Webview caching

```
WebView webView = new WebView( context );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 6 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 6MB size
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT ); // load online by default

if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) { // loading offline
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
}

webView.loadUrl( "http://www.stackoverflow.com" );
```

Check internet availability and add permission to your manifest file

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService( CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

permission for internet read and write storage

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```